# How do I create attributed line segments between two known points?

Tags: arcinfo-workstation

I have stream survey data that is spatially referenced every 10th habitat unit by a point.  There are 10 habitat units between each point along the survey and I need to figure out a way to spatially reference each individual habitat unit.  The habitat unit lengths are known from the survey but are not individually referenced.  Does anyone know how to complete this task?

Comment: You have an arcinfo-workstation tag but make no mention of that software in your Question body. Can you edit your Question to clarify whether that is the software that you are using, please?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using ArcMap. I can think of two ways to do this, if you require straight segments, [Points to Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003s000000) tool should do the trick.

If you require the line segment to curve alongside the stream, [Linear Referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003900000001000000) can be used.